# Is it possible to find the specs on a laser diode with the number on it?

Tags: laser, laser-diode

Laser n00b here,

I have a RGB[image] laser for festivals and music events, but only the red laser is functioning, I was hoping to replace the other two, as it's a relatively pricey unit. No luck contacting the manufacturer. Best I can tell, the text reads SB147FE91, picture attached. I have voltage on the leads, and no continuity in any polarity I can see, so I assume they're dead. Hopefully I can find an answer as google has turned up nada. Figured I'd see if anyone could find what I think is the blue before I bother with the other one. Thanks!

Comment: Not trying to be (too) snarky, but have you tried Googling it? How about Googling "SB147FE91 laser diode"? I bring this up because, while we are here to help, it is disrepectful not to even try to figure things out on your own.